# Accelerating Video Conversion

Tags: ffmpeg, video-encoding

I like to compress large video files before storing them to hard disk.  In Fedora-29-bash, I currently use the following ffmpeg command for re-encoding; it balances compression with quality:

```
ffmpeg -i $in_path -b:v 960k -bufsize 9600k -strict -2 $out_path
```

When executing the above command against a 2gb video file that has a 30 minute runtime, the execution will take about 20 minutes.  My hardware is shown at the end of this query.  **Can this video re-encoding be sped up?**

In other words, if I abandon ffmpeg in favor of any other software (e.g. handbrake), **will I attain faster re-encoding?** Based on my experiences copying files via bash (e.g. the cp or rsync commands) vs using the (nemo) file manager, my intuition is that nothing will beat the bash-ffmpeg performance.

**I am submitting this query just to double check my intuition.**

My Hardware

```
os         :  64 bit fedora 29
cpu        :  Intel I5-4440 Processor BX80646I54440
mobo       :  (64 bit) Gigabyte H97 SATA Express M.2 SSD UEFI DualBIOS  
           :  DDR3 1600 LGA
memory     :  32 gb : 2 x [G.Skill F3-1600C10D-16GAO Ares 16GB (2x8GB) 
           :  DDR3-1600Mhz Memory RAM]
psu        :  corsair cx series 600 watt
hdisk      :  1tb internal western digital wd10ezex sata
video card :  none - I use mobo's onboard video at 1920x1080.
sound card :  none - I use mobo's onboard audio
```

Comment: Which format are you saving to? MP4? MKV?

Comment: @Gyan Although my understanding is that mkv is superior, mp4 gives me good video, so that is what I am saving to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MKV or MP4, the default video codec is `libx264`, which has a set of presets, with different speed and quality tradeoffs. The default preset is `medium`. You can switch to a faster preset like `veryfast`. See list at https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264#crf

Comment: Interesting answer, thanks.  I wonder who downvoted my query, and why.